# python find last <div> in HTML

Tags: python, html, webdriver

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="issuePanelProgress">
    <div class="issuePanelContainer">
        <div class="comment-1196449"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="15.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 13 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196900"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="15.11.17 - 10:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 13 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196904"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="20.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 8 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196955"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="25.11.17 - 11:55">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 3 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1197000"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="28.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 6 hours ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code detect if the comment was written within the last 24 hours and from me, unfortunatly always the first comment in the HTML.

I want to check if **the last comment** is 24 hours ago and written from me.

I can´t use `driver.find_element_by_class_name("comment-1197000")` because I have to use the code for other pages with the same HTML structure and comments can be added. (so next comment would be **comment-1197001**)

This is my code so far:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver    

display = Display()
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

commentar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("issuePanelContainer")
if commentar.is_displayed():
    comment_author = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='issue_actions_container']").find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    author = comment_author.get_attribute("rel")
    written = driver.find_element_by_class_name("livestamp")
    last_comment = parse_date(written.get_attribute("datetime"))
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    if comment_author.get_attribute("rel") in author_list and last_comment < dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400): # 86400 Seconds for 24 h
        print "Last comment is from you and was written on", written.get_attribute("datetime")
    else:
        print "Last comment is not from you or older than 24 hours"
```

For a solution I thought about a for loop, but I'm new to python and I don't really know how to solve this problem.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: try using BeautifulSoup

Comment: try `rfind(<div>)`

Comment: What is `driver`? Is that Selenium? BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code behaves correctly. Selenium `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` returns the first element which matches.

You need to use `find_elements_by_class_name` (note plural) to get a list of all matching elements in document order and then use `writer = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("livestamp")[-1]` to get the last item in the list.

To get the comment `div`, you can use `writer.parent.parent`. Then, you can use [the `WebElement` methods](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) to find children and examine them.

Note: Usually, it's more simple to create a data structure, parse the document into the structure and then process the data structure. In your case, the structure would be the author, the text and the timestamp.

Iterate over the `div` children of `issuePanelContainer` and convert each into a new item.

Comment: That´s it .. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `BeautifulSoup` you can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="issuePanelProgress">
    <div class="issuePanelContainer">
        <div class="comment-1196449"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="15.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 13 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196900"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="15.11.17 - 10:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 13 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196904"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="20.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 8 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1196955"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="25.11.17 - 11:55">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 3 days ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-1197000"> 
            <span class="date user-tz" title="28.11.17 - 08:24">
                <time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 6 hours ago</time>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
item = soup.find('',{'class':'issuePanelContainer'})
last_item = item.find_all('div')[-1]
print(last_item)
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="comment-1197000">
<span class="date user-tz" title="28.11.17 - 08:24">
<time class="livestamp" datetime="2017-11-28T08:24:28+0100"> 6 hours ago</time>
</span>
</div>
```